# Grafana lucene query: Difference between fields.someFieldname = xxx and fields.someFieldname: xxx

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, lucene, grafana

I am writing a Grafana lucene query and when plotting fields.statusCode = xxx and fields.statusCode: xxx
I get two different totals, the first fx being 1200 while the second is 24.

Intuitively I would guess that the first one was more specific, but it gives a higher total.

What is the difference between ':' and '=' ?

**UPDATE** providing screenshots
Here is the screenshot using ":"

[image: query using ":"]

Here is the screenshot using "="

[image: query using "="]

as you can see, the only thing changed is the : vs = .

I've outmarked some parts of the pictures (which doesn't influence the question).

The first outmark in the query is simply the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lucene query, the correct operator to use is `:` not `=`, so `fields.statusCode:xxx` which yields 24 results is the correct way to do it.

More info can be found on [Lucene query parser syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description) documentation.

Whatever you write inside the `Query` field in Grafana will end up in the `query_string` below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "1571221609944",
              "lte": "1571223409944",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "fields.requestPath:\"bla bla bla\" AND XYZ AND method:POST"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see in the [`query_string` query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) (semantically equivalent to the one I shared above), the `:` is the character you need to use to separate field name and values.

Comment: Thanks you, Val, but what is the difference? '=' can be used too, even though it is not written in the documentation.

Comment: The `=` sign is usually used in URLs in the query string. Maybe if you show the full query it'll be easier to show you.

Comment: the query is actually just as in the question: "fields.myPath="someEndPoint" AND someOtherFilter" <- this gives a total count of approx. 5k. While "fields.myPath:"someEndPoint" AND someOtherFilter" only gives approx. 2.5k - therefore I am confused about what and how it differentiates, since it gives almost the double when using the "=" against the ":".

Comment: Again, the Lucene query language only knows about `:` not `=` which is an HTTP character for query string parameters. The Lucene query is encoded in one of those parameters

Comment: Alright, I understand that - that still doesn't clarify why I get different count values, but I think I will just let it be then.

Comment: You get different values because the queries are not the same with `:` (correct) or with `=` (incorrect)

Comment: I must from you have written presume, that I can not use the "=" hits to anything. I clearly understand from what you have written, that the use of "=" is incorrect and therefore I will not use it. It didn't answer why it gave double the amount of hits (if it is incorrect, it should not be able to be used imo), but no need to use more energy on that. It was just a curiosity, I seeked to satisfy. I will close it from here.

Comment: `=` is still an allowed character in an HTTP query string that's why it didn't error out, but the query is not interpreted the way you think. Can you add a screenshot of where you're adding this query?

Comment: Screenshots added